# Magento error 404: page not found on admin after upgrade to 1.9

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404, admin, upgrade

I've tried all solutions available online to this issue. Nothing worked and still getting a 404 error every time I login to my admin panel!

This issue has been occurring ever since I performed an upgrade for my site to 1.9.1.0 version of Magento.

here is a screenshot of the error: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0af3wfxfcb

What other information will you need to help me solve this issue?

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Did you overwrite .htaccess file located in magento root directory? Try to access panel using shop.com/index.php/admin

Comment: No I did not overwrite the htaccess file. And accessing the admin panel through shop.com/index.php/admin did not work either :(

Comment: how to solved my issue all of page give me error in homepage

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must have tried logging out after the upgrade, but just in case.

Try to go to phpmyadmin and disable secure backend and "Use Web Server Rewrites"

Hope this helps.

Comment: it should be in core_config_data

Comment: couldn't find "secure backend" or "use web server rewrites" in core_config data.. could it be in another table?

Comment: I haven't checked them myself but assume what you are looking for is this:  web/seo/use_rewrites,  web/secure/use_in_frontend, web/secure/use_in_adminhtml.   Go thorugh all web/*** records and see what might be wrong. If unsure what should be there you may do a fresh install of magento on a dev server and see its phpmyadmin.

Comment: Actually I'm starting to think that maybe the method of upgrade is wrong. I performed the upgrade using installron.. Do you recommend another method? (I am not familiar with CLI)

Comment: have a read the first answer of this [question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23931/magento-1-8-cant-upgrade-to-1-9). it worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL query:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Comment: I would suggest explaining as well as posting code.

Answer (score 0):

This problem often happens when you have upgraded your Magento store to new versions or installing security patches, even when you migrate/move your store to another server then your store was going down with 404 error – page not found on the frontend (maybe the same error is displayed in admin panel page also). This problem often cause by Magento cache is crashed/corrupted or something is conflicting when implement security patches (new code is applied). Or there was some incorrect entries, tables in database is missing when upgrading/moving your store.

For identifying exactly what’s the problem you can log in to FTP Client program (eg: **Filezilla**…) or server with File Manager and go to location `/var/report` and `/var/log` of Magento store files where its located (root directory) then checking error logs files (this may help resolve your problem also).

You can try the following solutions below to fixing it (via OIW blog):

- Clear Magento cache/session (even your browser also)
- Reset data of some tables, comparing them with original DB
- Check your Database if `default store` isn't active
- Check if it's `Mage::log()` error (Magento version 1.9.3+)

I hope this will help !